# Binomial distribution, inequality

Tags: probability-theory

Show that 
$$
P \left(X \ge \frac{K}{2}\right) \le \exp\left(\frac{-K}{8}\right)
$$
with $X$ following the law $\text{Bin}(K,\frac{1}{4})$

Answer (score 1):

Write $X = \sum_{i=1}^K X_i$ where $X_i $~ $Ber(\dfrac{1}{4})$.

Define $Y_i = X_i -\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $Y = \sum_{i=1}^K Y_i$.

Then $X\ge \dfrac{K}{2} \iff Y \ge \dfrac{K}{4}$. 
With the $Y_i$'s we can use Hoeffding's inequality which gives:

$P(X\ge \dfrac{K}{2} ) = P( Y \ge \dfrac{K}{4}) \le exp(\dfrac{-(\dfrac{K}{4})^2}{2K})=exp(\dfrac{-K}{8}$) as wanted.

---

Just for reminding:

Hoeffding's inequality says that if $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d random variables with $E[Z_i]=0$ and $|Z_i| \le 1$ then for $\alpha > 0$ , $P(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \ge \alpha) \le exp(-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2n})$.

Comment: Can you edit and adding the principles of Hoeffding's inequality adapted to your proof or it's too complicated and you really need this theorem without proof ?

Comment: Hoeffding's inequality says that if $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d random variables with $E[Z_i]=0$ and $|Z_i| \le 1$ then for $\alpha > 0$ , $P(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \ge \alpha) \le exp(-\dfrac{\alpha^2}{2n})$. 
Does that make it clear? @CechMS

Comment: i added it to my answer.

Comment: Okay... But are you sur it's too difficult to adapt the proof of this inequality to our question ?

Comment: what do you mean? i used this inequality because this is the easiest way i saw for solving this question..

Comment: Yeah but if this inequality is easy to proof then you can just do the proof instead of cite the theorem.

Comment: The proof isn't that easy if i remember correctly. @CechMS

Comment: One last thing... I think your result is $\exp(-\frac{K}{32})$ or it's because it's the morning where I am.